# Aligning html tables to get vertical line same for both

Tags: css, html

Hello I have these following tables for which I want same vertical line. please check my code here [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrBbfqpLyv7qhtJxxYTF?p=preview) I have two vertical tables, I want same vertical line of alignment for both the tables so that The line between two tables appears same though the tables are different.

Here is what I want [image: looks same vertical line between to tables] 
Here is what I am getting if I add text to th  [image: looks odd].
please tell me how can I make it better.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="1px" padding="20px">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <td>Savings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>January</th>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>February</th>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Monthasnsandf</th>
    <td>Savings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Januarydfsadfas</th>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Februarydfsadfsafa</th>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just set a static width to the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply specify the width for the `th` and `td` elements, say 50%.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table th, table td {
  width: 50%;
}
table th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="1px" padding="20px">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <td>Savings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>January</th>
    <td >$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>February</th>
    <td >$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="1px" padding="20px">
  <tr>
    <th>Monthasnsandf</th>
    <td>Savings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Januarydfsadfas</th>
    <td >$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Februarydfsadfsafa</th>
    <td >$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

what I did is put the two tables in another table which has 2 rows to perfectly match vertical alignment

```css
table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
  table th, table td {
      width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <td>Savings</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>January</th>
            <td >$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>February</th>
            <td >$80</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table  style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Monthasnsandf</th>
            <td>Savings</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Januarydfsadfas</th>
            <td >$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Februarydfsadfsafa</th>
            <td >$80</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I assume this is what you expect!